# Concordancia del adjetivo con sustantivos de géneros/números desiguales

Tags: concordancia-gramatical

No entiendo si o por qué es correcto utilizar la forma `ficticias` del adjetivo `ficticio` en la siguiente oración, dado que ni `el nombre` ni `una apariencia` son sustantivos **plurales** de género feminino:

> Uno se ve obligado a ocultar su verdadera identidad y a utlizar un
>   nombre y una apariencia **ficticias**.

Normalmente, se usa la forma plural genérica cuando hay sustantivos de dos géneros, ¿no? Tengo mis dudas en este caso porque es una frase que apareció en un libro publicado por un editorial de renombre. ¿Podría alguien aclarármelo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"apariencia" es femenino (LA apariencia).

De todos modos, la regla dice que, en caso de géneros diferentes, la concordancia debe ser en masculino y en plural:

> 3.2. Adjetivo pospuesto a varios sustantivos. Cuando un adjetivo califica a dos o más sustantivos coordinados y va pospuesto a ellos, lo más recomendable es que el adjetivo vaya en plural y en masculino, si los sustantivos son de distinto género: «Tiene el pelo y la barba enmarañados» (Matos Noche [Cuba 2002]); «Apareció [...] vestida con traje y mantilla blancos» (Hernández Secreter [Esp. 1995]). Si concordase solo con el último de los sustantivos, se generarían casos de ambigüedad, pues podría interpretarse que el adjetivo únicamente se refiere al más cercano: vestida con traje y mantilla blanca (¿el traje y la mantilla son blancos, o solo es blanca la mantilla?). No obstante, cuando los sustantivos coordinados se conciben como una unidad, de la que cada uno de ellos designa un aspecto parcial, el adjetivo puede concordar en género y número con el más próximo: «La gente de origen y habla francesa predomina en la provincia de Quebec» (Tiempo [Col.] 1.7.98). (Fuente: [DPD](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=XEVeLzVZaD6CG25cW5))

Por lo tanto, lo correcto sería decir:

- Uno se ve obligado a ocultar su verdadera identidad y a utlizar un nombre y una apariencia **ficticios**.

Comment: Entonces, es decir que el ejemplo no es correcto.

Comment: No. El ejemplo no es gramaticalmente correcto. Los artículos *un* y *una* te marcan la diferencia de género.